# How can I make JSTL give an error when referencing an undefined attribute

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Inside a jsp page, I would like JSTL to behave strictly when referencing an undefined variable.

Example:

### The servlet passes:

```
request.setAttribute("firstName", "hello");
request.setAttribute("lastName", "there");
```

### The jsp page:

```
${firstName} ${middleName} ${lastName}
```

I would like JSTL to give me an error that middleName is undefined instead of silently ignoring it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:if test="${empty middleName}">
  <c:out value="Middle name is empty"/>
</c:if>
```

OR

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${empty middleName}">
    <c:out value="Middle name is empty"/>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <c:out value="Middle name is NOT empty"/>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: No global flag in JSTL to enforce strict checking?

Comment: I never heared about it, so most likely no.